# projecting Tango 3D point to screen Google Project Tango

Tags: java, projection, google-project-tango, projection-matrix

Ptoject Tango provides a point cloud, how can you get the position in pixels of a 3D point in the point cloud in meters?

I tried using the projection matrix but I get very small values (0.5,1.3 etc) instead of say 1234,324 (in pixels).

I include the code I have tried

```
    //Get the current rotation matrix
    Matrix4 projMatrix =  mRenderer.getCurrentCamera().getProjectionMatrix();



    //Get all the points in the pointcloud and store them as 3D points
    FloatBuffer pointsBuffer =  mPointCloudManager.updateAndGetLatestPointCloudRenderBuffer().floatBuffer;
    Vector3[] points3D = new Vector3[pointsBuffer.capacity()/3];

    int j =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pointsBuffer.capacity() - 3; i = i + 3) {

        points3D[j]= new Vector3(
                pointsBuffer.get(i),
                pointsBuffer.get(i+1),
                pointsBuffer.get(i+2));
        //Log.v("Points3d", "J: "+ j + " X: " +points3D[j].x + "\tY: "+ points3D[j].y +"\tZ: "+ points3D[j].z );
        j++;
    }


    //Get the projection of the points in the screen.
    Vector3[] points2D = new Vector3[points3D.length];
    for(int i =0; i < points3D.length-1;i++)
    {
        Log.v("Points", "X: " +points3D[i].x + "\tY: "+ points3D[i].y +"\tZ: "+ points3D[i].z );
        points2D[i] = points3D[i].multiply(projMatrix);
        Log.v("Points", "pX: " +points2D[i].x + "\tpY: "+ points2D[i].y +"\tpZ: "+ points2D[i].z );
    }
```

The example I'm using is the point cloud java which can be found  here
https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java

---

UPDATE

```
TangoCameraIntrinsics ccIntrinsics = mTango.getCameraIntrinsics(TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);
    double fx = ccIntrinsics.fx;
    double fy = ccIntrinsics.fy;
    double cx = ccIntrinsics.cx;
    double cy = ccIntrinsics.cy;

    double[][] projMatrix = new double[][] {
            {fx, 0 , -cx},
            {0,  fy, -cy},
            {0,  0,    1}
    };
```

Then to compute the projected point I use

```
for(int i =0; i < points3D.length-1;i++)
    {

        double[][] point = new double[][] {
                {points3D[i].x},
                {points3D[i].y},
                {points3D[i].z}
        };

        double [][] point2d = CustomMatrix.multiplyByMatrix(projMatrix, point);

        points2D[i] = new Vector2(0,0);
        if(point2d[2][0]!=0)
        {
            Log.v("temp point", "pX: " +point2d[0][0]/point2d[2][0]+" pY: " +point2d[1][0]/point2d[2][0] );
            points2D[i] = new Vector2(point2d[0][0]/point2d[2][0],point2d[1][0]/point2d[2][0]);
        }

    }
```

But I think that the results are still not what is expected, I for instance get results like:

pX: -175.58042313027244 pY: -92.573740812066

Which to me looks not right.

---

UPDATE 
Using color camera as suggested gives better results, but poitns are still negative
-1127.8086915171814 pY: -652.5887102192332

Would it be ok to just multiply them by -1?

Comment: Use +cx and +cy for projMatrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to multiply 3D point with RGB camera's intrinsics matrix to obtain pixel coordinate. 3D points are in Depthcamera's frame. You get pixel coordinates by following method:

[image]

and

[image]

x and y are pixel coordinates.
And *K* is constructed with parameters using [intrinsics](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/intrinsics-extrinsics) function

[image]

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, I'll try it and let you know how it goes =)

Comment: Hey I'm looking at [link](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/java/reference/TangoCameraIntrinsics) which says pretty much what you're saying, but I'm unable to retrieve the camera intrinsics since I need a cameraId which I don't have =S, would you happen to know how to get them?

Comment: @Girauder you can get camera intrinsics, of RGB. From function tango provides, or else collect 7 images and perform camera calibration

Comment: Hi I think I manged with that, but the projected points are still negative, would multiplying them by -1 be ok? or is there something else wrong? I included the new code. Thanks for your help

Comment: Oops, CX and CY should be positive