# Getting coordinates and depth data of the point on video overlay using Project Tango

Tags: google-project-tango, rajawali

I'm looking to capture the coordinate data on the video overlay in project tango much similar to how measureit does it. How is this done?

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34565930/projecting-tango-3d-point-to-screen-google-project-tango/34639853#34639853). Similar requirement as yours.

Comment: Any idea how the touch position is obtained on the plane?

Comment: Checkout Augmented Reality unity3D example provided by Project-Tango

Comment: Right.. so none on Android.. We deifnitely have to take the Unity route for this?

Comment: You can obtain tough position in Android too. Look at source of Unity example. It's straightforward to port method into Android.